# How to implement OAuth2.0 with spring security by adding additional parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am implementing oauth2 with spring-security using springboot2 basing on below link.

https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-boot-oauth2-jwt-example

And i am successfull in implementing it.

Here i have different use case for the above code in authenticating user.

I need to pass companyid along with username and password and grant_type(password) in "x-www-form-urlencoded" tab in postman.
And i have to fetch User based on username and companyId.

So please help me out what changes i need to do in above link code so that i can achieve my requirement.

Here i am getting only email. I need email along with companyId.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(
            () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with -> username or email : " + email));
    return UserPrinciple.build(user);
}

Expected:

@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user = userRepository.findByEmailAndCompanyId(email,companyId).orElseThrow(
            () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with -> username or email : " + email));
    return UserPrinciple.build(user);
}
```

At present with username and password it is working fine.

But in my system i have same user mapped to different companies.if same user mapped to multiple companies found i am getting error like below.

{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "query did not return a unique result: 2; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2"
}

i need to fetch user based on username and password and companyId which results in single user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want additional information's with access tokens you can use TokenEnhancer class to do that.

CustomTokenEnhancer.java

```
public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();

        additionalInfo.put("id", user.getCompanyId());
        additionalInfo.put("authorities", user.getAuthorities());

        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);

        return accessToken;
    }

}
```

Then user the instance of this class to void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) method like this

AuthorizationServerConfig.java

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST)
            .tokenEnhancer(new CustomTokenEnhancer());
}
```